# using sed in loop

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have `.txt` files with the following structure:

```
20170515000650883,208,-32,-896,stand
20170515000651883,336,96,-928,stand
20170515000652982,368,64,-896,stand
20170515000653982,256,-48,-816,lie
20170515000654982,368,48,-832,lie
20170515000655982,15081,32,-688,lie
20170515000656982,15081,48,-864,lie
20170515000657983,15081,112,-1072,lie
20170515000658983,15081,-32,-992,lie
20170515000659983,15081,-48,-1072,lie
20170515000700983,15081,-32,-880,lie
20170515000701983,15081,16,-832,stand
20170515000702983,15081,-48,-720,stand
20170515000703983,15081,0,-896,stand
20170515000704983,15081,112,-880,lie
20170515000705983,15081,-48,-1072,lie
...
```

My goal is to search for `lie` events represented in the last column. This I realized with

```
sed -n '13,$s/lie/&/p' $subj > $SUBJECTS_DIR/temp.txt
```

where I started the search from line13 and saves all lines with 'lie' to my temp-file. But is it possible to collect data during the sed-command?
The first column contains a timestamp: so when lie=TRUE I want to collect the value from column_1; also, when the last lie of this sequence (in total 8 'lie' occurs the corresponding value of column_1 is needed to calculate the time-difference. The search should be continued until file ends.
Has someone any idea how to collect these informations during sed?

Comment: Wrong tool. `sed` can't do calculations itself. So you need to involve external tools (like using the `e` option to the `s` command in GNU `sed`) or implement it yourself (which can be fun, but is obviously nonsense). Switch to a tool like `python` or `perl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk for this.

> awk -F"," '/lie/{a[++i>2?2:i]=$1}END{print a[2] - a[1] }' input .txt

The awk command will store the first and the most recent timestamp that matches "lie" in an array. Once the file has been read, awk will subtract the first match from the last match.

Comment: Thanks for this line, it calculates exactly the difference I need! But is it possible to get multiple timestamp differences from one file? In my data example, there starts condition 'lie' in line3 and ends in line10; it starts again in line14 and ends in e.g. line22 following again a gap and 'lie' starts again in line34... and so on. How can awk automatically detect this?
Thnaks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear for me what is "time difference", but the first column with the "lie" can be simply expanded with this command:

`cat data.txt | grep lie | sed "s/,.*,lie//g"`

`grep` discards all lines without "lie" and `sed` deletes all except first column.

Then, you can f.e. transform it into array and work with needed numbers in bash

Comment: "time difference" means that in the above example I need to substract the value in first column of line 10 (describes a time) the the value in first column of line 3. This sequence of 'lie' is followed by a gap and the next sequence 'lie' starts again and so on. I want to have the length of this particular events...

Answer (score 0):

Probably Too Late to Be Posting This:

```
sed  -nE '13,$ s/([^,]*).*lie$/\1/p' in.txt
```

**Where:**

- `-nE`:
- - -n for --quiet, --silent : no automatic printing of pattern space.
- - `-E` for --regexp-extended : use extended regular expressions
- `([^,]*)` : captures the timestamp
- `.*lie$`  : ensures that the line ends with a 'lie'

**Thus:**
timestamps for "lie" starting from line 13 would be returned